# how to auto logout using $_SESSION or js timer?

Tags: php, javascript, symfony1

i read up on the topic but have no idea where to start
what will the first step be? i have this code that gets called first: rclayout.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <?php include_http_metas() ?>
    <?php include_metas() ?>
    <?php include_title() ?>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <?php use_stylesheet('rainbow.css');  ?>
    <?php use_javascript('rainbow.js'); ?>
    <?php include_stylesheets(); ?> 
    <?php include_javascripts(); ?>
</head>
<body onload='ax_startup();'>   
<center>
    <?php
       echo "<div id='div_main_container_rc'>"; 
    ?>
<div id='div_header_container_rc'>
   <?php include_component('profile','header'); ?>
</div>
    <?php       
            echo "<div id='div_content_container_rc'>";
            echo $sf_content;
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div id='div_footer'>";
    ?>
   //show a footer menu here
</div>  
</div> 
</center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

then _header.php is where it checks if a user is logged in:

```
<?php
$USR_IS_ADMIN = false;
$USR_AUTH     = false;

if($sf_user->hasAttribute('ADMIN'))
{
    $USR_IS_ADMIN = true;
}
    $id = $sf_user->getAttribute('profile_id');

    if($sf_user->hasAttribute('profile_id') > 0)
{   
      $profile = RcProfileTablePeer::getById($id);
      $activated = $profile->getActivated();
       if($activated == 1)
       {
        //echo "activated".$activated;
        $USR_AUTH = true;
       }
       else
       {
        //echo "NOT activated".$activated;
    $USR_AUTH = false;
        }
}
   ?>
   <?php if(!$USR_AUTH) : ?>
       //show a specific menu here   
   <?php endif;?>

  <?php if($USR_AUTH):?>
      //show a different menu here pertaining to logged in user
  <?php endif;?>
```

my  UPDATED factories.yml file:

```
prod:
  logger:
  class:   sfNoLogger
  param:
    level:   err
    loggers: ~

test:
  storage:
  class: sfSessionTestStorage
  param:
    session_path: %SF_TEST_CACHE_DIR%/sessions

response: 
  class: sfWebResponse
  param:
    send_http_headers: false

mailer:
  param:
    delivery_strategy: none

dev:
  mailer:
  param:
    delivery_strategy: none

all:
  routing:
  class: sfPatternRouting
  param:
    generate_shortest_url:            true
    extra_parameters_as_query_string: true

  view_cache_manager:
    class: sfViewCacheManager
    param:
      cache_key_use_vary_headers: true
      cache_key_use_host_name:    true

user:
  param:
     timeout: 300
```

where must i start how will i do this? i dont see a session set anywhere
do i configure the php.ini file and if so how? or do i do this with a session?

please help?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default PHP uses the PHP session mechanism. This session is configurated through the `factories.yml`. The default configuration is like this:

```
  user:
    class: myUser
    param:
      timeout:         1800
      logging:         %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
      use_flash:       true
      default_culture: %SF_DEFAULT_CULTURE%
```

So, by default, the session will automatically time out after 1800 seconds (= 30 minutes).

Your own `factories.yml` overrides the default `factories.yml` from Symfony (which can be found in `/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/config`). In that `factories`.yml`the user factory is defined like above.
So if that configuration is sufficient for you, you don't have to anything. If you want to change the timeout, you can override the appropriate lines in your own`factories.yml`. In that case you can add to following lines to your own`factories.yml`:

```
  user:
    param:
      timeout:         900  # log out after 15 minutes
```

Oh, and I really, strongly, recommend you to keep the logic out of the view in `_header.php`. All the PHP code with the `if`/`else` structures should be in the `components.class.php`, and te view (`_header.php`) should be only view data.

So something like this:

Controller:

```
// components.class.php
public function executeHeader() {

    // code here...
    $this->isAuthenticated = true/false;
}
```

View:

```
 <?php if ($isAuthenticated): ?>
 ...
 <?php enif; ?>
 <?php if (!$isAuthenticated): ?>
 ...
 <?php enif; ?>
```

Much cleaner, and it seperates the view from the logic... :-)

Comment: thank you very much please see my factories file at the top. can i just add your code or how do i configure mine please? from what i understand, user is a factory, so how do i know what name must i give to class??? thanks

Comment: thank you please see my updated factories file..i made it 300 so dont have to wait for 30/15 minutes to test this... can you explain what will happen after the timeout? i have my website open and a user logged in but nothing happens?? i can still continue on the website as i am still logged in?? thanks

Comment: When no requests are made to the webserver within the time out, the session expires. The first request after that will be given a new session, with no authentication properties set. (It's just default PHP Session behaviour, so you might want to just Google that)...

Answer (score 1):

Just destroy your session vars when you want with `session_destroy()`. if you don't know which session vars are set you can use something like this to print them out

```
 <?php 
 session_start(); 
 Print_r ($_SESSION);
 ?>
```

If you want to logout an user you need to `unset()` the user id too have a look to the php manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php (read description)